# mySQL query returning data even when the condition false

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query in mySQL to find a specific ID but the query returns data even when the conditions do not true.

```
SELECT `id`,`VCNCID` 
FROM `combinedsms`
WHERE `VCNCID`="737s"
```

As I do not have 737s in my table, so the result should be NULL.

But it returns all entries with 737 instead.

[image]

Comment: What is the dataType of column VCNCID ?

Comment: @Rakesh Jakhar, VCNCID dataType is int(11)

Comment: Then it's going to ignore the 's'.

Comment: Refer to this example too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08a25feee7c8e6613374cdab5df9f5df

Answer (score 0):

For the `INT` data type you don't need a `single quote` or `double quote`, simply try

```
SELECT id,VCNCID FROM combinedsms WHERE VCNCID=737
```